# Closed port on MAC OS, can't run docker image

Tags: oracle, macos, docker, port

I faced with problem. I need to run oracle-xe-11g on 49161:1521 on docker but get the error that 49161 port is used. How to free port?

Answer (score 0):

Try these sequence of steps:

1. List process running on port 49161: `lsof -i :49161`
2. Kill those process: `kill -9 process_id`

Comment: Do you have a knstance of MySQL on your machine? Go to System Preferences (on a Mac), click the tab for MySQL and disable Start MySQL when your computer starts up.

Comment: system prefrences -> user & groups -> click your user, go to "login items"